# Swift Core Data: FetchRequest with predicate over children

Tags: swift, core-data, predicate, fetchrequest

I have a Category entity with Scan child entities (one to many relationship).
Now I would like to fetch all Categories with a running a predicate on the children.

Details:
Category has a child relationship of Scans which is a Set.
Scan has an isSent bool which I want to use in the predicate.

I want to fetch all Categories but filter the Scan children by isSent = true.

This code does not work:

```
let scans: FetchRequest<Scan>
scans = FetchRequest<Category>(entity: Category.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        ], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "scans.isSent = %d", true))
```

Is there any way to write a FetchRequest with using a predicate on the children?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to fetch all Scans object where isSent is true then it’s better to directly fetch from Scans.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is the way I will go. I just thought it would have been more elegant if I could filter on child objects.